# how to change type array object to format object without looping method in vue.js?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object, vue.js

how to change type array object to format object without looping method in vue.js?

example:

```
// Data Array
data = [
    {
      id: 1,
      token: '123',
      name: 'name',
      contact: 'lorem ipsum',
    },
    {
        id: 1,
      token: '123',
      name: 'name',
      contact: 'lorem ipsum',
    },
]
```

to

`// Format Object
    {
        id: '',
        token: '',
        identity: {
            name: '',
            contact: ''
        },
    }`

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use `map`:

```js
const data = [{
    id: 1,
    token: '123',
    name: 'name',
    contact: 'lorem ipsum',
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    token: '123',
    name: 'name',
    contact: 'lorem ipsum',
  }
];

const newData = data.map(({ id, token, name, contact }) => ({
    id,
    token,
    identity: {
      name,
      contact
    }
}));

console.log(newData);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```